# socket.io emit on connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

new to socket.io and experimenting with it. this app is pretty simple, when i click the display button, an image appears on the screen in real time. i have 2 questions.

my main question: the images appear fine across all clients when added. my goal now is to get any new clients that connect to see the same data. for example, if i add 4 images to the screen, and then a new client connects, the new client does not see any images at all. seems my emit event is not triggering and i don't understand why. to explain my thought process behind it:

- after an image is appended, i clone the html container with jquery
  then convert to html.
- this data is successfully sent to the server, which i store in my
  jqueryImage variable
- i create another event, but it doesn't trigger on a client
  connection. (my 'append' event).

my other question: this doesn't happen all the time, but when there    are a couple of clients connected (about 7 or 8 ish) if i add lets    say 6 images, some of the clients will be out of sync. some will show    6 images, some will show 4, others 5, etc. i kind of attribute this    to my connection/lag but i'm not absolutely sure on that. is there a    way to check what this is and how would i aleviate that?

SERVER

```
 // app set up
    const app = express();
    const server = http.Server(app);
    // const  = new socket(server);
    let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    // static files
    app.use(express.static('app'));

    // socket setup & pass SERVER
    const io = new socketIO(server);

    let jqueryImage;

    // on client connect
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {


        console.log('made connection!!!');

        // events
        socket.on('client-image', function(data){
            console.log('SERVER ' + data.image);
            io.sockets.emit('client-image', data);
        });

        socket.on('new-client-append', function(data){
        jqueryImage = data.clone;
        console.log('jqueryImage ' + JSON.stringify(jqueryImage));
  });


io.on('connect', (socket) => {
  console.log('append emitting!!!');
  console.log('current clone ' + JSON.stringify(jqueryImage));

    socket.emit('new-client-append', jqueryImage);

});



    });



    // errors
    io.on('connect_error', function(){
        console.log('fail');
    });


    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log('server running....');
    });
```

CLIENT

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import SaveInput from './SaveInput';
import io from 'socket.io-client';



class Display extends SaveInput {

  constructor(){


    this.mainContainer = $('.main-container');
    this.pGrid = $('.pic-grid-container');
    this.display = $('#btn-display');

    this.buttons();
  }

  buttons (){

    // click buttons
    this.display.click(this.displayEls.bind(this));


  }

  //display images with names
  displayEls() {

    let img = 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/22f38e0216f57af53a1776fb2a72c436?s=60&d=wavatar&r=g';
    let $picContainer = $('<div class="picture-frame"></div>');
    let  $newImg = $('<img>');

    // clone pic-grid-container
    let htmlClone = this.pGrid.clone();
    let stringClone = htmlClone.html();

    // EMIT

    //send image url
    socket.emit('client-image', {
      image: img
    });

    // send dom clone to server
    socket.emit('new-client-append', {
      clone: stringClone
    });

    // LISTEN

    // append image in real time
    socket.on('client-image', (data) => {

        let foo = data.image.toString();

        $newImg.attr('src', foo);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(foo);
        $newImg.appendTo($picContainer);
        this.pGrid.append($picContainer);

        console.log('after append clone ' + stringClone);
    });

    socket.on('new-client-append', (data) => {
  console.log('NEW CLIENT ENTERED');

});

}

export default Display;
```

UPDATE: adjusted server code, server now emits, but client does not see it.

```
  //SERVER
socket.on('new-client-append', function(data){
        jqueryImage = data.clone;
        console.log('jqueryImage ' + JSON.stringify(jqueryImage));
  });


io.on('connect', (socket) => {
  console.log('append emitting!!!');
  console.log('current clone ' + JSON.stringify(jqueryImage));

    socket.emit('new-client-append', jqueryImage);

});

//client

 // send dom clone to server
    socket.emit('new-client-append', {
      clone: stringClone
    });

socket.on('new-client-append', (data) => {
      console.log('NEW CLIENT ENTERED');

    });
```

Comment: I think you can keep track of the clients who are connected to your server using an array. Whenever a client gets connected, you send all the images that have been sent to other clients who had connected to your server before this client.

Answer (score 4):

> seems my emit event is not triggering and i don't understand why. to explain my thought process behind it

You don't do `socket.on('connect', ...)` on the server (that's only for the client).  The socket is already connected when you get the `io.on('connect', function(socket) {...})` event on the server.  Just do the `socket.emit()` inside the `io.on('connect', function(socket) {...})`.

```
io.on('connect', function(socket) {
    socket.emit(...);
});
```

Comment: this change worked. always seems to be the smiple things... the server now emits, however my client still doesn't confirm the connection. i've adjusted the server code above

Comment: @user2247061 - You don't include enough client code for me to follow the whole client-side socket.io initialization all the way from connect through to listening for the `append` message.  I see `socket.on('append',...)` but don't know how the code gets there and/or what comes before that to properly set up the `socket`.

Comment: i changed the name of my 'new-client-clone' event to 'new-client-append'  to make a little more sense (hopefully) and added it to the post. on the client side, i'm sending the data through 'new-client-append'. the server receives this, and i store that data in the jqueryImage variable. i then emit this in the io.connect as you suggested, but it seems that the emit is still not happening.

Comment: @user2247061 - Does this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.  If not, then please indicate what is not yet answered.